# StaleElementReferenceException in iteration with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, staleelementreferenceexception

Hello I'm trying to scrap some info from t he following page:
http://verify.sos.ga.gov/verification/

My code is the following:

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select  
import time
import csv

url = 'http://verify.sos.ga.gov/verification/'

def init_Selenium():
    global driver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/rodrigopeniche/Downloads/chromedriver")
    driver.get(url)

def select_profession():
    select = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('t_web_lookup__profession_name'))
    options = select.options

    for index in range(1, len(options) - 1):
        select = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('t_web_lookup__profession_name'))
        select.select_by_index(index)
        select_license_type()

def select_license_type():
    select = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('t_web_lookup__license_type_name'))
    options = select.options

    for index in range(1, len(options) - 1):
        select = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('t_web_lookup__license_type_name'))
        select.select_by_index(index)
        search_button = driver.find_element_by_id('sch_button')
        driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', search_button)
        scrap_licenses_results()

def scrap_licenses_results():
    table_rows = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')

    for index, row in enumerate(table_rows):
        if index < 9:
            continue
        else:

            attributes = row.find_elements_by_xpath('td')

            try:
                name = attributes[0].text
                license_number = attributes[1].text
                profession = attributes[2].text
                license_type = attributes[3].text
                status = attributes[4].text
                address = attributes[5].text

                license_details_page_link = attributes[0].find_element_by_id('datagrid_results__ctl3_name').get_attribute('href')
                driver.get(license_details_page_link)

                data_rows = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('rdata')

                issued_date = data_rows[len(data_rows) - 3].text
                expiration_date = data_rows[len(data_rows) - 2].text
                last_renewal_day = data_rows[len(data_rows) - 1].text

                print name, license_number, profession, license_type, status, address, issued_date, expiration_date, last_renewal_day

                driver.back()

            except:
                pass

init_Selenium()
select_profession()
```

When I execute the script it works for the first iteration but fails in the second one. The exact place where the error is raised is in the scrap_licenses_results() function, in the `attributes = row.find_elements_by_xpath('td')` line.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The staleElementReferenceException is due to the list of rows gathered before loop iteration. Initially, You created a list of all rows ,named table_rows.

```
 table_rows = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')
```

Now in loop, during first iteration, your first row element is fresh and can be found by the driver. At the end of first iteration, you are doing `driver.back()`, your page changes/refreshes HTML DOM . All the previously gathered references are lost now. All the rows in your table_rows list are now stale. Hence, in 2nd iteration you are facing such exception.

You have to move the find row operation in the loop, so that everytime a fresh reference is found on target application. The psuedocode shall do Something like this.

```
total_rows = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr').length()

for i in total_rows
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//tr[i]')
    .. further code..
```